# Align span elements in div horizontally center

Tags: html, css

My problem is, that i cant align the span elements horizontally center or middle in the div, or inside the a element.

What i tryed, but didnt work:

```
.fejlec_kosar{text-align:center}
.fejlec_kosar a{display:block;text-align:center}
```

What am i doing wrong? My code looks like this:

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-xs-4 fejlec_kosar">
                <a href="<?php echo $host; ?>/kosar" title="Kosár">
                    <span class="header_kosar_text"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fejlec_kosar_ikon" aria-hidden="true"></i> Kosár</span>
                    <span id="header_kosar_text"></span>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </a>
            </div>


    .fejlec_kosar {
    margin-top: 18px;
    -webkit-transition: .3s linear;
    -o-transition: .3s linear;
    transition: .3s linear;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background-color: #fbab35;
    color: #173f62;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
.fejlec_kosar_ikon {
    color: #173f62;
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.header_kosar_text {
    color: #173f62;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    float: left;
    line-height: 30px;
}
#header_kosar_text {
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #d5902b;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: You can achieve that with flex box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you read in the comments, yo can achieve this using flexbox, what you need to do is

```
.fejlec_kosar {
    margin-top: 18px;
    -webkit-transition: .3s linear;
    -o-transition: .3s linear;
    transition: .3s linear;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background-color: #fbab35;
    color: #173f62;
    padding: 10px 0;
    display: flex; //ADDED
    justify-content: center; //ADDED
}
```

And that should work, [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) you have an article that will help you to understand how flexbox work;

Answer (score 0):

you can create same in other way. try below code snippet.

```css
.try-btn{
  width: 40%;
   margin-top: 18px;
    -webkit-transition: .3s linear;
    -o-transition: .3s linear;
    transition: .3s linear;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 25px !important;
    background-color: #fbab35;
    color: #173f62;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
   <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-4">               
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-default try-btn"><span class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></span> Kosár</a>
   </div>
</div>
```